# Bounded sequence in Sobolev Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Hi can anyone complete my solution (or give a better solution /hints to a better solution) to the following problem :

---

Define : The Sobolev Space $W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^{2})$ as 
$$W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^{2})=\{u~:~~ u\in L^4_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2), ~~ \Delta u\in L^4_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2),~~ u(x_{1}+1,x_{2})=u(x_{1},x_{2}),~~u(x_{1},x_{2}+1)=u(x_{1}+1,x_{2}),~~ \int_{(0,1)^{2}}u~=0 \} $$

Define : The functional $J:W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^2)\to \mathbb{R} $ (for some $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T}^2) $)

$$J(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{(0,1)^{2}}|Du|^2 + \int_{(0,1)^{2}}u_{x_{1}}^4+u_{x_{2}}^4 - \int_{(0,1)^{2}}fu$$

Show that if $J(u_{n})\to \inf_{u}J(u)$ then $\{ u_{n}\}$ is bounded in $W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^2)$.

$\bf{Hint}$ Use Poincare-Writinger inequality to justify why $\exists C>0$ s.t for any $u\in W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^2)$

$$||u||_{W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^2)}\leq C|| D u||_{W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^2)} $$

Note : $Du=(u_{x_{1}},u_{x_{2}})$

---

$\bf{My Attempt}$ ( note : we only need to bound the tail of the sequence)

Let $\epsilon>0$ using the definition of limit $\exists N$ s.t $\forall n>N$

$$| J(u_{n})-\inf J(u) | \leq \epsilon $$

Now using definition of infimum it follows

$$J(u_{n})\leq \epsilon +\inf J(u) $$
$$J(u_{n}) \leq \eta ~~~~ \forall n>N $$

Now were done if we can show $||u_{n}||_{W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^2)} \leq J(u_{n})$
Im struggling to extract $||u_{n}||_{W^{1,4}}(\mathbb{T}^2)$ from the above because of the $-\int_{(0,1)^2} fu_{n} $ term. I guess its a combination of Holder, $f$ zero average, and the 'hint'.

Comment: What is $\Delta$?

Comment: @timur Sorry I meant to write $||Du||_{W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^2)}$, I will edit now

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
|\int fu| \leq \|f\|_{L^2}\|u\|_{L^2}
\leq
\varepsilon\|u\|_{L^2}^2+\frac4\varepsilon\|f\|_{L^2}^2
\leq
C\varepsilon\|Du\|_{L^2}^2+\frac4\varepsilon\|f\|_{L^2}^2 ,
$$
where we have used the fact that $\int u=0$ in combination with the Poincare-Wirtinger inequality. Take $\varepsilon>0$ small enough, and get
$$
\|Du\|_{L^4}^4\leq\alpha J(u) + \beta
$$
for some constants $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: Is it obvious that we can apply Poincare-Wirtinger in this way for all $u \in W^{1,4}(\mathbb{T}^2)$

Comment: Thanks by the way, I should of thought to apply the epsilon young inequality it is used everywhere :)

Comment: @rogerroger: Yes, because the domain is bounded, there is the continuous embedding $W^{1,4}\subset W^{1,2}$.

Comment: and I assume you have used $u$ having zero average by not regarding it in your $||\cdot ||_{W^{1,4}}$ norm?

Comment: I don't know exactly which step you are referring to but you will need that at some point.

Comment: Well your last step you have $|| Du_{n} ||^4_{L^4}\leq \alpha J(u)+\beta$ but we need $||u_{n}||_{W^{1,4}}$ to be bounded

Comment: Yes of course you will need Poincare then.